# nunit won't redirect console output

Tags: nunit, nant

I'm using nunit 2.5 and when I try the following

nunit-console.exe "C:\Work\classLib\Data.Tests\bin\Debug\data.tests.dll" /out:output.txt

it still displays it on the console.

I can redirect ALL output by > output.txt of the whole command, but this doesn't work running in the context of NANT.

Any ideas?

EDIT: The NANT command is

```
<exec program="C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe
 " commandline="C:\Work\classLib\Data.Tests\bin\Debug\Data.Tests.dll
 " workingdir="C:\Work\classLib\Data.Tests\bin\Debug" output="output.txt" />
```

Cheers
Duncan

Comment: Can you paste the NAnt script segment that calls NUnit?

Answer (score 1):

/out=output.txt appears to be saving only items written out using Console.Writeline

The details of the test run are stored in an xml file, which you can redirect using the /xml switch.